# Scala Play evolutions not being applied

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to get Play's evolution feature to work.

I have this evolution saved under `conf/evolutions/suredbitsweb/1.sql`

```
#Email Table

# --- !Ups 

create table "EMAIL_LIST" ("ID" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"EMAIL" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL); 

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE "EMAIL_LIST";
```

and the following in my `application.conf` file

```
db.suredbitsweb.driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
db.suredbitsweb.username="postgres"
db.suredbitsweb.password="postgres"
db.suredbitsweb.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/suredbitsweb"
```

but play_evolutions table is not being created inside of the database `suredbitsweb`. Any insight as to why this is not working? Am I missing a configuration piece?

Comment: Does adding `db.suredbitsweb.applyEvolutions=true` fix it? Does it not prompt you to apply evolutions?

Comment: That did not work, and it does not prompt me to apply evolutions.

Comment: maybe try something like this `applyEvolutions.db=true`, cause everything else looks as same as in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `applyEvolutions.suredbitsweb=true`. Also check that you have `evolutionplugin=enabled`.